# How to draw Electron self energy diagram at 1 loop

Tags: diagrams, tikz-feynman, feynman

I have a little knowledge about drawing feynmandiagrams in latex,
I would like to add a diagram shown below to my latexfile in overleaf,(I need a big picture which cover half of the A4 size page) for that please help me...[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have read the [guide](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-feynman/tikz-feynman.pdf) to the pag. 22, and after much efforts, here there is your drawing....with the dots...

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.1.0}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=a to d] {
  a -- b [dot] -- [fermion,edge label'=\(p -q\)] c [dot] -- d [],
  b -- [photon, half left, looseness=1.5, momentum=\(q\)] c,
  a -- [momentum=\(p\)] b,
  c -- [momentum=\(p\)] d,
 };
\end{document}
```

[image]

and without the dots...

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.1.0}
\begin{document}


\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=a to d] {
  a -- b [] -- [fermion,edge label'=\(p -q\)] c [] -- d [],
  b -- [photon, half left, looseness=1.5, momentum=\(q\)] c,
  a -- [momentum=\(p\)] b,
  c -- [momentum=\(p\)] d,
 };

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple code with `pst-feyn` and `pst-node`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-feyn}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3.6,-0.4)( 3.6,2.8)
\psset{linejoin=1, arrowinset=0.2, arrowsize=4pt, labelsep=2.5pt}
\psArrowLine(-3.6,0)(3.6,0)
\psPhotonArc[amplitude=4pt,windings=8.5, radius=1.8](0,0)(0,180)
\psarcn{->}(0,0){2.4}{160}{20}
\pnodes(-3.3,0){A}(-2.3,0){B}(2.3,0){C}(3.3,0){D}
\psset{arrows=->, offset=2ex}
\ncline{A}{B}\naput{$p$}
\ncline{C}{D}\naput{$p$}
\uput[d](0,0){$ p-q $}
\uput[u](0,2.4){$q$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For my humble opinion the tips of the arrows are better using `pst-feyn` instead of `tikz-feynman` (see the big tip near `p-q`).

Comment: For me, they're comparable. The only difference is that it's easier for me to find the parameters details with pstricks, because I've been using it for more than 20 years and I'm  more familiar with it (I even had a friend who didn't use it: he directly typed the postscript code!)/

Comment: I'm totally agree with you. I have started my initial picture using `pstricks` of Herbert Voss 18 years ago, and I'm really sad he's out of this community and a lot of good people.

Comment: @Sebastiano This is a new account of Herbert Voss: https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/187802/user187802. I think you know! :-)

Comment: @user213378 No, absolutely. I always vote this user :-) I thinked that the user was a woman. :-( Peraphs for the pink avatar. I'm happy that is here: Herbert Voss. I think also a Christian Hupfer...very good user for tcolorbox, and others....